# http2: PUSH_PROMISE client-side stream state

Tags: http2, server-push, push-promise

The [http2 spec](http://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#rfc.section.6.6) says:

> A receiver MUST treat the receipt of a PUSH_PROMISE on a stream that
>   is neither "open" nor "half-closed (local)" as a connection error
>   (Section 5.4.1) of type PROTOCOL_ERROR. However, an endpoint that has
>   sent RST_STREAM on the associated stream MUST handle PUSH_PROMISE
>   frames that might have been created before the RST_STREAM frame is
>   received and processed.

The spec also has this [lifecycle diagram](http://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#rfc.section.5.1).

My understanding is that in order for a client to receive a `PUSH_PROMISE` on a stream, the client must have **all** of these on that stream:

- sent `HEADERS` frame (+ any `CONTINUATION`s) to the server
- not received `END_STREAM` flag from the server
- not received `RST_STREAM` frame from the server

(Notably missing here is "not sent `RST_STREAM` frame to the server”, which would lead to the stream being "closed"; the quote above says this is not grounds for connection error.)

In any case where these criteria are not met, then the client must treat receiving a PUSH_PROMISE as a connection error.

Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: Your understanding could be correct, but the question is a bit ambiguous because it doesn't specify which end would have sent which frame, for the `RST_STREAM` and `HEADERS` frame in particular.

Comment: I’ve updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

The HTTP/2 protocol associates `PUSH_PROMISE` streams to an existing stream, called the *associated stream*.

The associated stream must meet the conditions defined in the section of the specification quoted in the question; the bullet list in the question is another way of saying the same thing that the specification section says.